# webserivce is called from my jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, service, web

I have created a code like this to access method AddNums in my webservice. I am sending data through webservice to get output. but it is not giving any output.

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <script src="scripts/Jquery%20v1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        alert('I have been clicked');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:5554/Service1.svc",
            data: "{2,3}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#output").text(msg.d);
            }
        });

    });
    });

    </script>
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">

      <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me" /> <br /> <br />

       <span id="output"></span>

       </form>
      </body>
       </html>
```

Implementation of webserivce. I have tested webservice with inbuilt client in Visual Studio, it is working perfectly.

```
  namespace WcfServiceTest
  {

    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
   public class Service1 : IService1
   {
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }

   [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse = false)]
    public int AddNums(int val1, int val2)
    {
        return (val1 + val2);
    }

     }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need this awful whitespace in your filename? Usually people use `_` or `-` or `.` in that case.

Comment: I'm not hugely familiar with ASP, so I could be wrong, but shouldn't you be POSTing 'val1=1&val2=2' instead of JSON?

Comment: And shouldn't you use just 'msg' instead of 'msg.d' when outputting the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong way

```
data: "{2,3}",
```

Right Way is

```
data: {para1:value1,para2:value2},
```

for passing the parameter to external file.

Comment: Hi, I made changes to that, even then it is not working.$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            alert('I have been clicked');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:5554/Service1.svc/AddNums",
                data: '{val1:"2",val2:"3"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#output").text(msg.d);
                }
            });

        });
    });

Comment: the problem i see in your code is that you are wrapping the data parameter in single quote that is not required. also after url parameter semicolon is not required. The val1 and val2 have become a post variable because you are using post request so get these variable in your server file like 
$_POST['val1'] and so on.